# \bar allowed only in math mode error for a table

Tags: tables, amsmath

I got a TeX error for the following table and I don't know why...

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Here are all average values, as well as the standard deviation to them, of the different planet types in all systems of the population J39 with HJ listed.}
    \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bar{N}_{all}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\sigma_{N_{all}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bar{N}_{mig}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\sigma_{N_{mig}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bar{N}_{sca}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\sigma_{N_{sca}}} \\
    Min M_E & 5.81  & 4.88  & 10.39 & 3.74  & 2.23  & 1.25 \\
    earthlike & 1.31  & 1.71  & 2.52  & 1.81  & 0.4   & 0.81 \\
    superearths & 1.6   & 2.45  & 3.43  & 2.73  & 0.13  & 0.35 \\
    giants & 1.19  & 0.89  & 0.87  & 1.01  & 1.43  & 0.68 \\
    d-burning & 0.25  & 0.52  & 0     & 0     & 0.43  & 0.63 \\
    AMD   & 1247.54 & 4292.39 & 10.95 & 43.72 & 2154.01 & 5402.85 \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab: System values for different planet types in all HJ Systems}%
\end{table}%
```

Can someone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! The error message tries to tell you that you need to use math modes at several locations of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Here are all average values, as well as the standard deviation to them, of the different planet types in all systems of the population J39 with HJ listed.}
    \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\bar{N}_\mathrm{all}$} &
      \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\sigma_{N_\mathrm{all}}$} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\bar{N}_\mathrm{mig}$} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\sigma_{N_\mathrm{mig}}$} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\bar{N}_\mathrm{sca}$} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{l}{$\sigma_{N_\mathrm{sca}}$} \\
    $\min M_E$ & 5.81  & 4.88  & 10.39 & 3.74  & 2.23  & 1.25 \\
    earthlike & 1.31  & 1.71  & 2.52  & 1.81  & 0.4   & 0.81 \\
    superearths & 1.6   & 2.45  & 3.43  & 2.73  & 0.13  & 0.35 \\
    giants & 1.19  & 0.89  & 0.87  & 1.01  & 1.43  & 0.68 \\
    $d$-burning & 0.25  & 0.52  & 0     & 0     & 0.43  & 0.63 \\
    AMD   & 1247.54 & 4292.39 & 10.95 & 43.72 & 2154.01 & 5402.85 \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab: System values for different planet types in all HJ Systems}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer, but when I insert the table inside my text I get the error: Argument of math@egroup has an extra }. What does this mean?

Comment: @MichiKovac Do you load `amsmath` in your document?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest some improvements in the layout of the table.

1. Enclose the tabular in a [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) environment, which is an easy way to line up the caption with the table
2. Use [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to draw some horizontal rules
3. Use [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) to typeset the columns with decimals. Alternatively, you may use [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) and `\newcolumntype` to construct a right aligned maths column, and then normalise all figure by adding zeros so you have same number of decimals (0.40, 0.00 *etc.*) (see example 2).
4. Remove left and right side bearing (`@{}`)
5. Always put the `label` inside the `caption`-command (best practise).

**Example 1 - [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, booktabs, threeparttable, array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
  \centering
  \caption{Here are all average values, as well as the standard deviation to them, of the different planet types in all systems of the population J39 with HJ listed\label{tab:System-values}}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l
                    *{6}{S[table-format=4.2]}
                    @{}}
\toprule
      & $\bar{N}_\mathrm{all}$   &
      $\sigma_{N_\mathrm{all}}$ & 
      $\bar{N}_\mathrm{mig}$     & 
      $\sigma_{N_\mathrm{mig}}$ & 
      $\bar{N}_\mathrm{sca}$        & 
      $\sigma_{N_\mathrm{sca}}$ \\
      \midrule
    $\min M_E$ & 5.81  & 4.88  & 10.39 & 3.74  & 2.23  & 1.25 \\
    earthlike & 1.31  & 1.71  & 2.52  & 1.81  & 0.4   & 0.81 \\
    superearths & 1.6   & 2.45  & 3.43  & 2.73  & 0.13  & 0.35 \\
    giants & 1.19  & 0.89  & 0.87  & 1.01  & 1.43  & 0.68 \\
    $d$-burning & 0.25  & 0.52  & 0     & 0     & 0.43  & 0.63 \\
    AMD   & 1247.54 & 4292.39 & 10.95 & 43.72 & 2154.01 & 5402.85 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

**Example 2 - [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) and `\newcolumntype`**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, booktabs, threeparttable, array}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{$}r<{$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
  \centering
  \caption{Here are all average values, as well as the standard deviation to them, of the different planet types in all systems of the population J39 with HJ listed\label{tab: System values for different planet types in all HJ Systems}}

    \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{6}{Z}@{}}
\toprule
      & \bar{N}_\mathrm{all}   &
      \sigma_{N_\mathrm{all}} & 
      \bar{N}_\mathrm{mig}     & 
      \sigma_{N_\mathrm{mig}} & 
      \bar{N}_\mathrm{sca}        & 
      \sigma_{N_\mathrm{sca}} \\
      \midrule
    $\min M_E$ & 5.81  & 4.88  & 10.39 & 3.74  & 2.23  & 1.25 \\
    earthlike & 1.31  & 1.71  & 2.52  & 1.81  & 0.40   & 0.81 \\
    superearths & 1.60   & 2.45  & 3.43  & 2.73  & 0.13  & 0.35 \\
    giants & 1.19  & 0.89  & 0.87  & 1.01  & 1.43  & 0.68 \\
    $d$-burning & 0.25  & 0.52  & 0.00     & 0.00     & 0.43  & 0.63 \\
    AMD   & 1247.54 & 4292.39 & 10.95 & 43.72 & 2154.01 & 5402.85 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
  \centering
  \caption{Here are all average values, as well as the standard deviation to them, of the different planet types in all systems of the population J39 with HJ listed\label{tab:System-values}}

    \begin{tabular}{@{}l
                               *{6}{S[table-format=4.2]}
                               @{}}
\toprule
      & $\bar{N}_\mathrm{all}$   &
      $\sigma_{N_\mathrm{all}}$ & 
      $\bar{N}_\mathrm{mig}$     & 
      $\sigma_{N_\mathrm{mig}}$ & 
      $\bar{N}_\mathrm{sca}$        & 
      $\sigma_{N_\mathrm{sca}}$ \\
      \midrule
    $\min M_E$ & 5.81  & 4.88  & 10.39 & 3.74  & 2.23  & 1.25 \\
    earthlike & 1.31  & 1.71  & 2.52  & 1.81  & 0.4   & 0.81 \\
    superearths & 1.6   & 2.45  & 3.43  & 2.73  & 0.13  & 0.35 \\
    giants & 1.19  & 0.89  & 0.87  & 1.01  & 1.43  & 0.68 \\
    $d$-burning & 0.25  & 0.52  & 0     & 0     & 0.43  & 0.63 \\
    AMD   & 1247.54 & 4292.39 & 10.95 & 43.72 & 2154.01 & 5402.85 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Schrödinger's cat's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508953/134144), I'd suggest the following layout using `siunitx` and `booktabs`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Here are all average values, as well as the standard deviation to them, of the different planet types in all systems of the population J39 with HJ listed.}
    \begin{tabular}{l
    *{2}{S[table-format=4.2]}
    *{2}{S[table-format=2.2]}
    *{2}{S[table-format=4.2]}}
    \toprule
      & {$\bar{N}_\mathrm{all}$} &
      {$\sigma_{N_\mathrm{all}}$} & 
      {$\bar{N}_\mathrm{mig}$} & 
      {$\sigma_{N_\mathrm{mig}}$} & 
      {$\bar{N}_\mathrm{sca}$} & 
      {$\sigma_{N_\mathrm{sca}}$} \\
    \midrule
    $\min M_E$ & 5.81  & 4.88  & 10.39 & 3.74  & 2.23  & 1.25 \\
    earthlike & 1.31  & 1.71  & 2.52  & 1.81  & 0.4   & 0.81 \\
    superearths & 1.6   & 2.45  & 3.43  & 2.73  & 0.13  & 0.35 \\
    giants & 1.19  & 0.89  & 0.87  & 1.01  & 1.43  & 0.68 \\
    $d$-burning & 0.25  & 0.52  & 0     & 0     & 0.43  & 0.63 \\
    AMD   & 1247.54 & 4292.39 & 10.95 & 43.72 & 2154.01 & 5402.85 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab: System values for different planet types in all HJ Systems}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```